# Data corruption of local variable when passing to another function

Tags: c, corruption

How is data corruption possible when passing local variable on stack to a function call?

```
{
    int Array[4];

    Array[0] = 1;
    Array[1] = 2;
    Array[2] = 3;
    Array[3] = 4;

    test_struct->arr = Array;
    //(Where arr is a pointer to array)
    Demo(test_struct);
}
```

What could go wrong if Array is passed to another function here? Is there possiblity of 
data corruption?

Comment: What do you mean by "data corruption"?  Can you also show us the definition of `test_struct` and the implementation of `Demo` please?

Comment: Please post some more code. Also, where is this 'data corruption' happening?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if `Demo()` has bugs that causes it to write outside the bounds of `Array`, which it can't know anything about, it can of course corrupt memory, yes.

Note that you can't use `sizeof` inside `Demo()` to figure out the size, you must have a separate argument (or struct member) telling the number of elements available.